# How can implement custom javascript code in Grafana?

Tags: grafana

I'm new to Grafana.

I made a dashboard and there is a table.

I'd like to implement the feature that runs Javascript code when clicking the table cell item.

Ideally, to achieve this, I will add a specific class name to the table cell to be clicked, and add a click listener with this class name to perform the corresponding operation.
But I can't figure out where to put the custom JS code to do this.

So I tried a different way.

Here's what I've tried:

If I put the correct URL(for example https://google.com) in the URL field of the cell attribute on the edit panel, then it is rendered as `<a href="https://google.com">`

Inspired by this, I put the following code in that URL field, but it doesn't work.

```
javascript:alert("Hello World")
```

It was rendered as `<a href="black page" ...>`
something like this.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Yes, that's my question.
I want to put some code to do some customization, but I can't figure out where and how to put it in the Grafana dashboard project.